# Static cells from xib in UICollectionViews with segues (Swift 2)

Tags: swift2, uicollectionview, xcode7, xib, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to create list of rows using UICollectionView with each row can click and go to another controller.
I create custom cell in xib and class for it.

[image]

This is my code:

```
class CollectionCellXIB: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
}


class Collection: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell: CollectionCellXIB
    self.collectionView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CollectionCellXIB", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
         cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionCellXIB
         cell.label.text = "cell 1"
    } else {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionCellXIB
        cell.label.text = "cell 2"
    }

    return cell
}
```

}

Unfortunatelly, segues not working. When I clicked on a row, nothing happend. Method shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier wasn't called.

So, question is, how to use custom cells with xib and using segues?